# I want to find the minimum two values in one array with doing any sorting

Tags: assembly

Following code is my try to find the minimum two values that are in the frequency table. I don't want to use any sorting algorithms. As soon as i detect the two smallest values in the array. I save their indexes and perform addition on that. So far i have done this. Can anyone please help me with this? That now what do i have to do. Thanks

```
freq   dd 512 dup(0)
min    dw ? 

smallval proc
push bx
sub bx,bx

cal:
mov ax,freq[bx]  ;moving the address of frequence to source index
cmp ax,0        ;comparing the frequency array one by one
jmp incr        ;increased the address of frequency by two since its a byte
call check
mov freq[bx],0  ;replace that min value with zero
mov ind,bx 

cal1:
add bx,2        ;now trying to find the next smallest value in the array
mov ax,freq[bx]
cmp ax,0
jmp cal1
call check
mov freq[bx],0
add ax,min      ;addition of two minimum values

incr:
add bx,2
jmp cal

endval:
smallval endp

;=======================================================================================
;checking for the smallest value in the array

check proc
mov ax,freq[bx]          ;assigning lowest value in the frequency array in min 
variable
mov min,ax

l1:                       ;loop that checks each value of array with min 
variable
add bx,2                  ;and see if something is smaller then that will be a 
new min
mov ax,freq[bx]
cmp min,ax
jge assign
cmp bx,1024
jmp end
jmp l1

assign:                   ;upon next smallest value min variable will be 
replaced by that
mov ax,freq[bx]           ;smallest value
mov min,ax
jmp l1

end:
ret
check endp
```

Comment: _"So far i have done this. Can anyone please help me with this?"_ Describe what you have done, and what you're having trouble with specifically.

Comment: H.N., post the declaraton of the array.

Comment: ok i am doing it right now

Comment: No, there is a frequent mistake in your code where you use a `cmp` instruction but instead of making a conditional branch such as `jne` you ignore the result of the comparison and `jmp`, which is unconditional. Please see my answer.

Comment: okay i am checking it right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
cal1:
add bx,2
mov ax,freq[bx]
cmp ax,0
jmp cal1
```

and some dubious flow control here:

```
cmp bx,1024
jmp end
jmp l1
```